# Start mysql server right after installation - password issue, AlmaLinux

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords, almalinux

I have installed mysql at AlmaLinux 8.7: `sudo dnf  install mysql-server`
Yet as I try to start it there is the password prompt:

```
$ systemctl start mysql
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'mysql.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

what should be a password ?
Without it the outcome is the following:

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Failed to start mysql.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.
```

### Update 1

After I did `sudo su root` the issue got the following:

```
[root@89 etc]# systemctl start mysql
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

### Update 2

I've made the **mysql.service** and **mysqld.service** files with the same content as [here](https://superuser.com/a/384525/259471) is shown.
Then `systemctl daemon-reload`.

### Update 3

Seems I've started it :

```
[root@89 system]# systemctl start mysql
[root@89 system]# ps ax | grep mysql
 261841 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

# namei -l /var/lib/mysql-files
f: /var/lib/mysql-files
dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x root  root  lib
drwxr-x--- mysql mysql mysql-files



# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-04-26 14:03:06 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 261830 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld>
 Main PID: 261830 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 26 14:03:06 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
Apr 26 14:03:06 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 26 14:03:06 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

yet, when `[root@89 system]# mysql`

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server 
through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

**Why is that ?**